# Toggle between layouts in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3.   I have a layout with a screen-height column on the left and three panes on the right (see figure below).  This setup is great (especially with the Golden Ratio plugin), but I still miss one feature I had in vim.  I had a hotkey that caused the pane that had focus to take up the entire window, like entering full-screen mode for that one file.  When done, you could enter the hotkey again to revert to your previous layout.  It's as if the original layout of the panes is saved, and the focused pane temporarily takes over the whole window, and when you're done editing the file full-screen, the program remembers how things were laid out and reverts to that.  Here's an ASCII-art example:

```
          BEFORE                                 AFTER
----------------------------          ----------------------------
|            |             |          |                          |
|            |             |          |                          |
|            |-------------|          |                          |
|            |             |          |                          |
|            |             |          |                          |
|            |-------------|          |                          |
|            |             |          |                          |
|            |             |          |                          |
----------------------------          ----------------------------
```

By typing a hotkey, you switch from `BEFORE` to `AFTER`; typing the same hotkey again reverts you to `BEFORE`, with the same layout and the same tabs in each pane.

Is there a way to do this in Sublime Text 3, including a plugin that might enable this?  If the reader knows how to write Sublime plugins, how hard do you imagine writing such a plugin would be?  I would guess it wouldn't be too bad: a matter of stashing state somewhere and programatically telling Sublime to revert to that when switching back from full-screen mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is a year on, but the MaxPane plugin solves this problem.

https://github.com/jisaacks/MaxPane

Install through package manager, and then use Command Shift Enter to toggle a pane between full screen and within whichever layout you are using.

Comment: This is a very nice plugin, and I use it to solve this problem.  Although Origami was probably the best answer when the question was asked, this is probably the best answer now.  Origami is still excellent and solves most of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You may try using [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami), it helps organising layouts, it doesn't have what you want, but it has a Zoom functionality, here's a quote from the author:

> Additionally, Origami allows one to zoom the current pane, making it
>   take up a large portion of the window. As above, first press super+k,
>   then press:
>
> super+z: Zoom the current pane so it takes up 90% of the screen (the
>   fraction is changeable in the keybindings) shift+super+z: Unzoom:
>   equally space all panes (Note: Windows and Linux use ctrl instead of
>   super.)

There's no way to do what you want currently, though you may try writing a plugin yourself

Comment: This is a very good solution!  Not exactly what I said, but gives me pretty much all I want.

Comment: @door_number_three glad it fits you. considering your needs it's quite difficult to achieve as it requires some complex logic on whether tabs should be closed when you go to a single panel view or merged to it and what should happen when you switch back to four panel view - it would require tab allocation to exact panel to work smoothly, otherwise, it's a hassle to rebuild your workspace by dragging tabs to their panels

Answer (score 0):

You could also chose **1**, a single panel default switcher: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>

https://superuser.com/questions/368785/switch-between-columns-active-tabs-in-sublime-text-2/424987#424987